# Use select in group by statement in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using a Firebird database which has the following tables:

ARTICULOS

| ProductId | longSKU |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A22121000125 |
| 2 | A22121000138 |
| 3 | A22123001508 |
| 4 | A22124002001 |

TALLESPORARTICULOS

| ProductId | position | Sizes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Small |
| 1 | 2 | Medium |
| 1 | 3 | Large |
| 1 | 4 | Xtra Large |
| 1 | 5 | XXtra Large |
| 2 | 1 | Small |
| 2 | 2 | Medium |
| 2 | 3 | Large |
| 2 | 4 | Xtra Large |
| 2 | 5 | XXtra Large |
| 3 | 1 | 02 |
| 3 | 2 | 04 |
| 3 | 3 | 06 |
| 3 | 4 | 08 |

and
RANGOSTALLE

| ProductId | FromPosition | ToPosition | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 500 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 600 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 500 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 600 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 200 |

I want to be able to group by a substring (shortSKU) of the longSKU and be able to get for each shortSKU the corresponding ranges and prices.

like this example:

| ShortSKU | SizeFrom | SizeTo | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A221210001 | small | large | 500 |
| A221210001 | xtra large | xxtra large | 600 |
| A221230015 | 02 | 08 | 200 |

I'm using the following cobe but I get the error:

> Dynamic SQL Error.
>
> > SQL error code = -104.
> > Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the >GROUP BY clause).

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW RANGOSPARACOSTOSYPRECIOS(
SHORTSKU,
SIZEFROM,
SIZETO,
PRICE ) AS select substring(ar.codigoparticular from 1 for 10) AS SHORTSKU,
( Select TAL.SIZE 
  From tallesporarticulos TAL 
  Where TAL.productid=Ar.productid 
  and TAL.position= RT.FromPosition) as SIZEFROM,
( Select TAL.SIZE 
  From tallesporarticulos TAL 
  Where TAL.productid=Ar.productid 
  and TAL.position= RT.ToPosition) as SIZETO,
  max(RT.PRICE)
from Articulos Ar
Inner Join tallesporarticulos TA On Ar.productId = TA.productId
Inner Join rangostalle RT On AR.productId = RT.productId
GROUP BY SHORTSKU, SIZEFROM, SIZETO ;
```

The following code works, but I need to replace the "fromposition" and "ToPosition" values with the size value like the code above, and that's when I get the error message.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW RANGOSPARACOSTOSYPRECIOS(
SHORTSKU,
SIZEFROM,
SIZETO,
PRICE ) AS select substring(ar.codigoparticular from 1 for 10) AS SHORTSKU,
RT.FromPosition as SIZEFROM,
RT.ToPosition as SIZETO,
  max(RT.PRICE)
from Articulos Ar
Inner Join tallesporarticulos TA On Ar.productId = TA.productId
Inner Join rangostalle RT On AR.productId = RT.productId
GROUP BY SHORTSKU, SIZEFROM, SIZETO ;
```

For anyone interested in helping, here you have the insert data from the tables above.

```
CREATE TABLE articulos (
  ProductId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  LongSKU varchar(12) NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (1, 'A22121000125');
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (2, 'A22121000138');
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (3, 'A22123001508');
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (4, 'A22124002001');

CREATE TABLE TALLESPORARTICULOS (
  ProductId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Position INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Sizes varchar(12) NOT NULL
  );
INSERT INTO TALLESPORARTICULOS (ProductId, position, Sizes) VALUES
(1, 1, 'SMALL'),
(1, 2, 'MEDIUM'),
(1, 3, 'LARGE'),
(1, 4, 'XTRALARGE'),
(1, 1, 'XXTRALARGE'),
(2, 2, 'SMALL'),
(2, 3, 'MEDIUM'),
(2, 4, 'LARGE'),
(2, 5, 'XTRALARGE'),
(2, 5, 'XXTRALARGE'),
(3, 1, '02'),
(3, 2, '03'),
(3, 3, '04'),
(3, 4, '05');

CREATE TABLE RANGOSTALLE (
  ProductId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FromPosition INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ToPosition INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Price double not null
  );

INSERT INTO RANGOSTALLE (ProductId,FromPosition,ToPosition,Price) VALUES 
(1, 1,3,500),
(1, 4,5,600),
(2, 1,3,500),
(2, 4,5,600),
(3, 1,4,200);
```

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? I suspect a very old one, because recent versions would produce an error _"Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 5, column 11 position"_ as `POSITION` is a reserved word. Also, your query doesn't have a column SHORTSKU (did you maybe partially translate your example?), so I would suspect it would fail with an error because of that. It would also be helpful if you provide the necessary DDL (and some INSERT for test data).

Comment: Hi! it's true, I translated the query and field names couse they were in spanish so there is no "position". I also edited the query couse I forgot to translate CODCORTO as ShortSKU.
I'm using Firebird 2.5 couse I'm working with the company's ERP database.

Comment: In your example there is no grouping by shortSKU as code A221210001 is shown twice and it is not clear what you want to be in the result if there are more ranges and prices for any given SKU.

Comment: The table "rangostalle" has four defined ranges for products ID '1' and '2', which are equivalent to the shortSKU 'A2221210001'. Each set of ranges has it's own price.
What I need is to group ShortSKU - Range and to obtain the corresponding price.
Therefore shortSKU would have 2 groupings 
'A2221210001' range 1 to 3 price 500
'A2221210001' range 4 to 5 price 600

In addition, I want to replace the "range position" with the corresponding size.

Sorry, it's my first time using StackOverflow, thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Please do not add the `psql` tag - it's intended for questions around the command line client from [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). If you want to include a tag for the _procedural_ language in Firebird, use `firebird-psql`. But that's only necessary if you want a solution for a stored procedure or function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script contains quite a few errors. After fixing them the query is rather trivial:

```
select substring(LongSKU from 1 for 10), low.sizes, high.sizes, avg(price)
from articulos join RANGOSTALLE on articulos.ProductId = RANGOSTALLE.ProductId
join TALLESPORARTICULOS low on RANGOSTALLE.ProductId = low.ProductId and RANGOSTALLE.FromPosition = low.Prodposition
join TALLESPORARTICULOS high on RANGOSTALLE.ProductId = high.ProductId and RANGOSTALLE.ToPosition = high.Prodposition
group by 1,2,3
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=ae54a7d897da4604396775e3ddc4b764

This query can be optimized by moving grouping into a derived table but such optimization highly depends on the real table structure and query requirements.

Comment: The shortskus in the example are 10 characters long, so it should be `for 10`

Comment: Ah, indeed, I missed one counting digits.